# Can I use Ubuntu's back up for Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, backup

I've keep taking my Ubuntu box's backup like a good boy (deja-dup) and recently I've decided to erase Ubuntu and install Lubuntu in its place. (I want to go easy on my old box and let it have something light weight).
so I'd like to know if I could use my Ubuntu backup after installing Lubuntu and restore my box to my earlier state. I only backup my Documents, Pictures, Downloads and Videos directories. So I think I may be able to pull this off, but being a noob I may also be very very wrong. Would anybody help me please?

Comment: Any software available for any official Ubuntu version can be used in any of the others. Mind though: you will pull in ALL the dependencies too so it is best to avoid it since it might strain your poor computer more than you expected ;) Backing up your own directories  does not require sofware; you could just copy/paste it onto a USB :)

Comment: Ok, got that. Thanks for the advice of using usb. Though I've found deja-dup to be safer and faster than pasting whole directories :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is no reason that shouldn't work, assuming that your backup is stored somewhere off the PC in question. (Sorry, but I had to bring it up - you'd be surprised where people put their backups...)

Although Deja-Dup is quite opaque and it's hard to figure out what it's doing sometimes, it has served me well.

If I were doing what you propose, I'd take a Clonezilla clone of my current system first, so I could get back to where I started, if things go south.

Comment: Whoa, that was fast! Thanks for taking time to help me. (And I do store my backups on an external hard drive.) Will post back after trying this.